# Too many re-renders and nothing is working as expected. useEffect, useState, localStorage, syncfusion

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, syncfusion

[Syncfusion React Schedule Component] Hi everyone, first post here, and I'm desperate. Took on this new job and I'm expected to do stuff with react I haven't dealt with before. There are many many problems with this code so I'm taking anything you guys point out. First of all I cannot exclude title/subject property from events because they throw my code in the trash, I'm also having trouble with quickInfoTemplate (I wanted to disable it and use the eventClick/cellClick prop of schedule component to trigger the customTemplateEditor instead. I also wanted to trigger an automatic change in endtime according to hours spent on the project but since im using props at  I have no idea how to do that (if anyone knows how to do that I can provide the code snippet for that component too). But the things is really the useEffect where localEvents are mapped (code snippet provided by my boss, I've never dealt with window.addEventListener which is being triggered a thousand times), it's triggering too many rerenders and I have no idea what to do to fix it, after some changes to try and fix it now the application stops to prevent an infinite loop everytime I try to add a new event (not sure about the eventChange or delete because I cannot get there). Syncfusion documentation is really poor or I'm too much of a newbie, either way any lights on any of that would be awesome

```
import { ButtonComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-buttons";
import {
  Agenda,
  Day,
  Inject,
  Month,
  ScheduleComponent,
  Week,
  WorkWeek,
} from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CustomEditorTemplate from "./EditorTemplate";
import "./MainContent.css";

export default function ScheduleCalendar() {
  // Ref
  let scheduleObj;
  const currentView = "Month";
  // State

  const [localData, setLocalData] = useState([]);
  const [requestData, setRequestData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const localStorageData = localStorage.getItem("appointments")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("appointments"))
      : [];
    setLocalData(localStorageData);
  }, []);

  const onActionComplete = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("appointments", JSON.stringify(localData));
  };
  // ScheduleOPS
  const fieldsData = {
    id: "id",
    subject: { name: "subject" },
    startTime: { name: "startTime" },
    endTime: { name: "endTime" },
    hours: { name: "hours" },
    budgetHrs: { name: "budgetHrs" },
    description: { name: "description" },
    totalTime: { name: "totalTime" },
    project: { name: "project" },
    task: { name: "task" },
    workCode: { name: "workCode" },
    customer: { name: "customer" },
  };

  const onActionBegin = (args) => {
    /* console.log(args); */
    args.data && setRequestData(args.data);
  };
  /* console.log(requestData[0]); */
  const editorTemplate = (props) => {
    return props !== undefined ? <CustomEditorTemplate /> : <div></div>;
  };

  const handleOpenEditor = () => {
    const cellData = {
      startTime: new Date(),
    };
    scheduleObj.openEditor(cellData, "Add");
  };

  // EventHandles
  const onEventCreate = () => {
    if (requestData.length) {
      const validateData = localData.filter((item) => {
        return item.id === requestData[0].id;
      });
      /*       console.log(validateData); */
      if (validateData.length) {
        alert("This event already exists.");
      } else {
        const updatedData = [...localData, requestData[0]];
        /*         console.log(updatedData); */
        setLocalData(updatedData);
      }
    }
  };

  const onEventChange = () => {
    if (requestData.length) {
      const updatedData = localData.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== requestData[0].id) {
          return item;
        } else {
          return requestData;
        }
      });
      console.log("updatedData", updatedData);
      if (localData === updatedData) {
        alert("No change detected.");
      } else {
        setLocalData(updatedData);
      }
    }
  };

  const onEventDelete = () => {
    if (requestData.length) {
      const updatedData = localData.filter((appointment) => {
        //console.log(requestData[0]);
        return appointment.id !== requestData[0].id;
      });
      setLocalData(updatedData);
    }
  };

  const localEvents = [
    { eventName: "eventCreate", eventHandler: onEventCreate() },
    { eventName: "eventChange", eventHandler: onEventChange() },
    { eventName: "eventDelete", eventHandler: onEventDelete() },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    localEvents.map((e) => {
      return window.addEventListener(e.eventName, e.eventHandler);
    });

    return () => {
      const removeListener = localEvents.map((e) => {
        return window.removeEventListener(e.eventName, e.eventHandler);
      });
      return removeListener;
    };
  }, []);

  const eventTemplate = (props) => {
    return <div className="template-wrap">{props.customer}</div>;
  };

  return (
    <ScheduleComponent
      ref={(t) => (scheduleObj = t)}
      currentView={currentView}
      eventSettings={{
        dataSource: localData,
        fields: fieldsData,
        template: eventTemplate.bind(this),
      }}
      editorTemplate={editorTemplate.bind(this)}
      actionBegin={onActionBegin}
      actionComplete={onActionComplete}
    >
      <div className="e-toolbar-items e-tbar-pos">
        <ButtonComponent
          iconCss="e-icons e-date-time"
          className="e-control e-btn"
          id="targetButton1"
          onClick={handleOpenEditor}
        />
      </div>
      <Inject services={[Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month, Agenda]} />
    </ScheduleComponent>
  );
}
```

I've tried adding that onActionComplete to see if that worked something out but nothing. It actually came to the point where all the previous data I had in localStorage was somehow deleted because of the new logic I put down. I'm really looking for any inputs/ideas

Comment: When you define `localEvents` you are calling the handler instead of assigning it to `eventHandler`. Change `eventHandler: onEventCreate()` to `eventHandler: onEventCreate`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ej2-react-schedule-editortemplate-sample?file=index.js

**Q1: I cannot exclude title/subject property from events because they throw my code in the trash**

If you don’t want the subject field in the appointment change the subject field to another field that you want in the appointment. Here I changed the **subject** field to **customer** field. Or remove the **subject** field from the **editorTemplate**.

**[index.js]**

```
function ScheduleCalendar() {
    let scheduleObj;
    const fieldsData = {
        id: "id",
        subject: { name: "customer", default: "" },
        startTime: { name: "startTime" },
        endTime: { name: "endTime" },
        description: { name: "description" }
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ScheduleComponent eventSettings={{  fields: fieldsData }} editorTemplate={editorTemplate.bind(this)} >
            </ScheduleComponent>
        </div>
    );
}
export default ScheduleCalendar;
```

(or)

**[editor-template.js]**

```
function EditorTemplate(props) {
  let data = props?.data;
  // const [subject, setSubject] = useState(data?.subject);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(data?.description);

  return (
    (data !== undefined && Object.keys(data).length > 0) ?
      <table className="custom-event-editor" style={{ width: '100%' }} cellPadding={5}>
        <tbody>
          {/* <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">Subject</td>
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <input id="subject" className="e-field e-input" type="text" data-name="subject" value={subject} style={{ width: '100%' }} onChange={(args) => { setSubject(args.target.value) }} />
            </td>
          </tr> */}
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">Customer</td><td colSpan={4}>
              <DropDownListComponent id="customer" placeholder='Choose customer' data-name='customer' value={data.customer} className="e-field" style={{ width: '100%' }} dataSource={['Customer one', 'Customer two', 'Customer three']}>
              </DropDownListComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      :
      <div></div>
  );
};

export default EditorTemplate;
```

**Q2: I'm also having trouble with quickInfoTemplate. I wanted to disable it and use the eventClick/cellClick prop of schedule component to trigger the customTemplateEditor instead**

To disable the quick info popup set up the **args.cancel = true** in the **popupOpen** event of the Schedule when the popup type is **QuickInfo** and open the editor instead using the **openEditor** method.

**UG:**
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/editor-template#how-to-prevent-the-display-of-editor-and-quick-popups

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/how-to/open-event-editor-manually

**API:**
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/schedule/#popupopen
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/schedule/#openeditor

**[index.js]**

```
const onPopupOpen = (args) => {
    if (args.type == "QuickInfo") {
        args.cancel = true;
        var currentAction = args.target.classList.contains("e-work-cells") ? "Add" : "Save";
        scheduleObj.openEditor(args.data, currentAction);
    }
}
```

**Q3: I also wanted to trigger an automatic change in endtime according to hours spent on the project**

You can set automatically change the **endTime** according to the hours spent on the project by changing the state of the **endTime** field of the **editorTemplate** as shown in the below code snippet. In the below example, I changed the **endTime** value when the hours or **startTime** values changes using their change event.

**UG:**
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/editor-template#customizing-event-editor-using-template

**API:**
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/datetimepicker#change
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/numerictextbox#change

**[editor-template.js]**

```
function EditorTemplate(props) {
  let data = props?.data;
  const [start, setStart] = useState(data?.startTime);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(new Date(start?.getTime() + (data?.id ? 0 : 7200000)));
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(data?.hours | 2);
  // const [subject, setSubject] = useState(data?.subject);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(data?.description);

  const startChange = (args) => {
    setStart(args.value);
  }

  const hourChange = (args) => {
    setHours(args.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (start && hours) {
      setEnd(new Date(start.getTime() + (hours * 3600000)));
    }
  }, [start, hours]);

  return (
    (data !== undefined && Object.keys(data).length > 0) ?
      <table className="custom-event-editor" style={{ width: '100%' }} cellPadding={5}>
        <tbody>
          {/* <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">Subject</td>
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <input id="subject" className="e-field e-input" type="text" data-name="subject" value={subject} style={{ width: '100%' }} onChange={(args) => { setSubject(args.target.value) }} />
            </td>
          </tr> */}
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">Customer</td><td colSpan={4}>
              <DropDownListComponent id="customer" placeholder='Choose customer' data-name='customer' value={data.customer} className="e-field" style={{ width: '100%' }} dataSource={['Customer one', 'Customer two', 'Customer three']}>
              </DropDownListComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">From</td>
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <DateTimePickerComponent id="startTime" format='dd/MM/yy hh:mm a' data-name="startTime" value={start} change={startChange.bind(this)} className="e-field"></DateTimePickerComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">To</td>
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <DateTimePickerComponent id="endTime" format='dd/MM/yy hh:mm a' data-name="endTime" value={end} enabled={false} className="e-field"></DateTimePickerComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">Work hours</td>
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <NumericTextBoxComponent id="hours" className="e-field e-input" data-name="hours" min={2} value={hours} change={hourChange.bind(this)} />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      :
      <div></div>
  );
};

export default EditorTemplate;
```

**Q4: I've tried adding that onActionComplete to see if that worked something out but nothing.**

To perform CRUD actions with the Schedule, use the **actionBegin** event of the Schedule as shown in the below code snippet.

**API:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/schedule/#actionbegin

**[index.js]**

```
function ScheduleCalendar() {
    let scheduleObj;
    const [scheduleModel, setScheduleModel] = useState({
        currentAction: "InitialRendering",
        currentView: "Week",
        selectedDate: new Date(2021, 1, 15),
        dataSource: localStorage.getItem("appointments") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("appointments")) : []
    });

    function editorTemplate(props) {
        return <EditorTemplate data={props}></EditorTemplate>;
    }

    function onActionBegin(args) {
        if (["eventCreate", "eventChange", "eventRemove"].indexOf(args.requestType) > -1) {
            // Prevent the default CRUD action by setting up true
            args.cancel = true;
            let resultData = extend([], scheduleModel.dataSource, null, true);
            if (args.addedRecords.length > 0) {
                // Adding appointment
                resultData = resultData.concat(args.addedRecords);
            }
            if (args.changedRecords.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < args.changedRecords.length; i++) {
                    const index = resultData.findIndex((data) => { return data.id === args.changedRecords[i].id });
                    // Updating appointment
                    resultData[index] = args.changedRecords[i];
                }
            }
            if (args.deletedRecords.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < args.deletedRecords.length; i++) {
                    const index = resultData.findIndex((data) => { return data.id === args.deletedRecords[i].id });
                    // Deleting appointment
                    resultData.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
            // Update the state with the new data
            localStorage.setItem("appointments", JSON.stringify(resultData));
            setScheduleModel(prevState => ({ ...prevState, dataSource: resultData }));
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ScheduleComponent eventSettings={{ dataSource: scheduleModel.dataSource }} editorTemplate={editorTemplate.bind(this)} actionBegin={onActionBegin.bind(this)} >
            </ScheduleComponent>
        </div>
    );
}
export default ScheduleCalendar;
```

Make sure that you added the **“e-field”** class name and **name** attributes to the input elements of the **editorTemplate**. So, the Schedule automatically recognizes those input fields and includes them in the appointment.

**[editor-template]**

```
function EditorTemplate(props) {
  let data = props?.data;
  const [start, setStart] = useState(data?.startTime);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(new Date(start?.getTime() + (data?.id ? 0 : 7200000)));
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(data?.hours | 2);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(data?.description);

  return (
    (data !== undefined && Object.keys(data).length > 0) ?
      <table className="custom-event-editor" style={{ width: '100%' }} cellPadding={5}>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">Customer</td><td colSpan={4}>
              <DropDownListComponent id="customer" placeholder='Choose customer' data-name='customer' value={data.customer} className="e-field" style={{ width: '100%' }} dataSource={['Customer one', 'Customer two', 'Customer three']}>
              </DropDownListComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">From</td>
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <DateTimePickerComponent id="startTime" format='dd/MM/yy hh:mm a' data-name="startTime" value={start} change={startChange.bind(this)} className="e-field"></DateTimePickerComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">To</td>
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <DateTimePickerComponent id="endTime" format='dd/MM/yy hh:mm a' data-name="endTime" value={end} enabled={false} className="e-field"></DateTimePickerComponent>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">Description</td>
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <textarea id="description" className="e-field e-input" name="description" rows={3} cols={50} style={{ width: '100%', height: '60px !important', resize: 'vertical' }} value={description} onChange={(args) => { setDescription(args.target.value) }}></textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td className="e-textlabel">Work hours</td>
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <NumericTextBoxComponent id="hours" className="e-field e-input" data-name="hours" min={2} value={hours} change={hourChange.bind(this)} />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      :
      <div></div>
  );
};
```